# Maui control events

Tags: c#, xaml, controls, maui

Where are Maui control events documented?
I have searched for documentation, but have only found examples where a single event is used.
It's easy to find windows forms control events documentation.

Comment: for some reason there aren't complete API docs published for MAUI yet.  You can refer to the Xamarin Forms API docs, which will be fairly similar for most controls.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: I’m working on that and they should be there soon. However it will take a while before they all have a useful description as well.